# ModelNotFoundError when deploying machine learning model on ACI

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

Please am trying to deploy a machine learning model on ACI but am having this error below at the final stage when trying to deploy the model as a  webservice on Azure. Help advise on how to fix it.

```
2020-08-10T11:01:28,103498848+00:00 - rsyslog/run 
2020-08-10T11:01:28,109724839+00:00 - nginx/run 
2020-08-10T11:01:28,111248110+00:00 - gunicorn/run 
EdgeHubConnectionString and IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME are not set. Exiting...
2020-08-10T11:01:28,192849628+00:00 - iot-server/finish 1 0
2020-08-10T11:01:28,194532107+00:00 - Exit code 1 is normal. Not restarting iot-server.
Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:31311 (18)
Using worker: sync
worker timeout is set to 300
Booting worker with pid: 42
SPARK_HOME not set. Skipping PySpark Initialization.
Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d31cd964833447a6573171273c4f1235/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d31cd964833447a6573171273c4f1235/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d31cd964833447a6573171273c4f1235/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d31cd964833447a6573171273c4f1235/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d31cd964833447a6573171273c4f1235/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d31cd964833447a6573171273c4f1235/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d31cd964833447a6573171273c4f1235/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/azureml-server/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import create_app
  File "/var/azureml-server/create_app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import main
  File "/var/azureml-server/app.py", line 31, in <module>
    import main as user_main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
Worker exiting (pid: 42)
Shutting down: Master
Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-08-10T11:01:28,524618650+00:00 - gunicorn/finish 3 0
2020-08-10T11:01:28,526020716+00:00 - Exit code 3 is not normal. Killing image.
```

Here is the scoring script am using. Please advise if I need to import any function. Everything seems okay to me. Find it difficult to identify any issue

````
from azureml.contrib.services.aml_request import AMLRequest, rawhttp
from azureml.contrib.services.aml_response import AMLResponse
import json


from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.contrib.services.aml_request import AMLRequest, rawhttp
from azureml.contrib.services.aml_response import AMLResponse

# Done - Faster
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sentence_transformers import models, losses
import scipy.spatial
import pickle as pkl
import pickle

import pandas as pd
import os

from collections import OrderedDict
  

import re
def clean_text(text):
  
  text = re.sub('\r\n','\n',text)
  text = re.sub('\r','',text)
  text = re.sub(r'\s+',' ',text)
  text = re.sub(r'\n',' ',text)

  return text
  
  
def init():
  
  print("This is init()")
  
  global model, on_path, ifc_inv, ifc_adv, wb_lend, wb_adv, smart_lesson, ifc_inv_data_map, ifc_adv_data_map, wb_lend_data_map, wb_adv_data_map, smart_lesson_data_map

  on_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name='Docker_custom_KP_model', version = 2)
  
  
  ## Read in Data Files Fix
  ifc_inv =  pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/ifc_data/ifc_inv.csv'),  lineterminator='\n')
  ifc_adv =  pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/ifc_data/ifc_adv.csv'), lineterminator='\n')

  # WB data
  wb_lend =  pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/wb_data/wb_lend.csv'), lineterminator='\n')
  wb_adv  =  pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/wb_data/wb_adv.csv') , lineterminator='\n')

  # Lesson data
  smart_lesson = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/lesson_data/smart_lesson.csv'),  lineterminator='\n')

  
  
  ## Read in Data Map #Fix
  ifc_inv_data_map = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/ifc_inv_data_map.csv'))
  ifc_adv_data_map = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/ifc_adv_data_map.csv'))

  wb_lend_data_map = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/wb_lend_data_map.csv'))
  wb_adv_data_map = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/wb_adv_data_map.csv'))

  smart_lesson_data_map = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/smart_lesson_data_map.csv'))
  
  ## Drop irrelevant columns
  ifc_inv.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  ifc_inv_data_map.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  
  ifc_adv.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  ifc_adv_data_map.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  
  wb_lend.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  wb_lend_data_map.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  
  wb_adv.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  wb_adv_data_map.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  
  smart_lesson.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  smart_lesson_data_map.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
  
    
    
  ## CLean data
  # ## TOOD - After UAT
  ifc_inv['Project_Description'] = ifc_inv['Project_Description'].map(clean_text)
  ifc_adv['Project_Description'] = ifc_adv['Project_Description'].map(clean_text)

  wb_lend['proj_abstract'] = wb_lend['proj_abstract'].map(clean_text)
  wb_adv['proj_abstract'] = wb_adv['proj_abstract'].map(clean_text)

  smart_lesson['Abstracts'] = smart_lesson['Abstracts'].map(clean_text)
  
  ## end Clean data
  
  
  
  ## Read in Models
  #word_embedding_model = models.BERT('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/dev/models/BERT_model_new/') ## fix
  word_embedding_model = models.BERT(os.path.join(on_path,'model_dir/')) 

  # Applying mean pooling to get one fixed sized sentences vector
  pooling_model = models.Pooling(word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension(),
                                 pooling_mode_mean_tokens = True,
                                 pooling_mode_cls_token = False,
                                 pooling_mode_max_tokens = False
                                )

  model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model])

  
def text_to_embedding(model, in_text):
  
  query_embeddings = model.encode(in_text, show_progress_bar=True)
  return query_embeddings


    
@rawhttp
def run(request):
  
  print("This is run()")
  print("Request: [{0}]".format(request))
  if request.method == 'GET':
    # For this example, just return the URL for GETs.
    respBody = str.encode(request.full_path)
    return AMLResponse(respBody, 200)
  
  elif request.method == 'POST':
    
    reqBody = request.get_data(False)
    
    in_text = json.loads(reqBody)['input_query']
    in_text = [in_text]
    
    req_page = json.loads(reqBody)['request_page']
    
    n_row = json.loads(reqBody)['n_request']
    n_row = int(n_row)

    if req_page == 'IFCInvestment':
      
      relevant_file_dir = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/ifc_data/ifc_inv.csv')
      data_map = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/ifc_inv_data_map.csv')

      #vector_dir = './KPrequest/inference_data/' + request_page + '/faiss_inv.index'

      with open(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/embeddings/embedding_ifc_inv.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        corpus_vecs = pickle.load(f)

      vec = text_to_embedding(model, in_text)
      #vec = [vec]

      relevant_df = ifc_inv  #pd.read_csv(relevant_file_dir, lineterminator='\n')
      data_map_df = ifc_inv_data_map #pd.read_csv(data_map)

      #relevant_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
      #data_map_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)


    if req_page == 'IFCAdv':

      relevant_file_dir = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/ifc_data/ifc_adv.csv')
      data_map = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/ifc_adv_data_map.csv')

      #vector_dir = './KPrequest/inference_data/' + request_page + '/faiss_inv.index'

      with open(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/embeddings/embedding_ifc_adv.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        corpus_vecs = pickle.load(f)

      vec = text_to_embedding(model, in_text)
      #vec = [vec]

      relevant_df = ifc_adv  #pd.read_csv(relevant_file_dir, lineterminator='\n')
      data_map_df = ifc_adv_data_map #pd.read_csv(data_map)

      #relevant_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
      #data_map_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)


    if req_page == 'IFCLesson':
      
      relevant_file_dir = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/lesson_data/smart_lesson.csv')
      data_map = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/smart_lesson_data_map.csv')

      #vector_dir = './KPrequest/inference_data/' + request_page + '/faiss_inv.index'

      with open(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/embeddings/embedding_smart_lesson.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        corpus_vecs = pickle.load(f)

      vec = text_to_embedding(model, in_text)
      #vec = [vec]

      relevant_df = smart_lesson  #pd.read_csv(relevant_file_dir, lineterminator='\n')
      data_map_df = smart_lesson_data_map #pd.read_csv(data_map)

      #relevant_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
      #data_map_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)


    if req_page == 'WBLend':

      relevant_file_dir = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/wb_data/wb_lend.csv')
      data_map = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/wb_lend_data_map.csv')

      #vector_dir = './KPrequest/inference_data/' + request_page + '/faiss_inv.index'

      with open(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/embeddings/embedding_wb_lend.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        corpus_vecs = pickle.load(f)

      vec = text_to_embedding(model, in_text)
      #vec = [vec]

      relevant_df = wb_lend  #pd.read_csv(relevant_file_dir, lineterminator='\n')
      data_map_df = wb_lend_data_map #pd.read_csv(data_map)

      #relevant_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
      #data_map_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)


    if req_page == 'WBAdv':

      relevant_file_dir = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_file/wb_data/wb_adv.csv')
      data_map = os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/data_map/wb_adv_data_map.csv')

      #vector_dir = './KPrequest/inference_data/' + request_page + '/faiss_inv.index'

      with open(os.path.join(on_path,'Assets/embeddings/embedding_wb_adv.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        corpus_vecs = pickle.load(f)

      vec = text_to_embedding(model, in_text)
      #vec = [vec]

      relevant_df = wb_adv #pd.read_csv(relevant_file_dir, lineterminator='\n')
      data_map_df = wb_adv_data_map  #pd.read_csv(data_map)

      #relevant_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)
      #data_map_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1, inplace= True)


    distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(vec, corpus_vecs, "cosine")[0]

    results = zip(range(len(distances)), distances)
    results = sorted(results, key = lambda x: x[1])
    

    result_index = list(map(lambda x: x[0],results))
    map_index = data_map_df.iloc[result_index]

    proj_index = map_index['Index'].to_list()
    unique_proj_index = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(proj_index))

    relevant_df.fillna('', inplace=True)

    kp_dataframe = relevant_df.loc[unique_proj_index[0: n_row]]
    kp_result = kp_dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')

    resp = AMLResponse(json.dumps(kp_result), 200)
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

    return resp
  
  else:
    return AMLResponse("bad request", 500)```
````

Comment: Can you share your scoring script and the code you used to define the service?

Comment: Have added my score script @AndersSwanson

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with your scoring script. Can you share your inference config, deployment config, and code you use to deploy?